# Excel 07 - declaring and sorting chunks of arbitrary size

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, sorting

Let's say I have a list of Abbreviations:

[image]

As you can see, the only layout "rule" is a blank line between entries.
I should now like to sort them by their abbreviation:

[image]

Using Excel07 and having no experience whatsoever with it, how would I best achieve that?

Comment: The problem is, you've used many rows for descriptions. If you made the description all fit into 1 row, you could use the normal Table and filter the rows...

Comment: You have a mess to work with here.  If there aren't too many values, it will probably be quicker to manually manipulate (think CONCANTENATE) your values into a two cell pairs: `Abbreviation:Definition` (or three, if you add categories).  Then, convert your data into a table for manipulation, or MS Word for better word processing options.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, you'll need to consolidate your descriptions.  To do this:

1. Add a new column, let's assume C.  And starting in C2 and copy down this formula.  It will concatenate from the bottom up for each group (with a space and a line-feed/Alt-enter to keep the lines intact as originally written).

   `=IF(ISBLANK(B2),"",B2&" "&CHAR(10)&C3)`
2. Then, select Column C, Copy->Paste Values so that the descriptions are not re-written on re-sorts.  Also, make sure Wrap Text is turned on for this column
3. Filter the list of blank abbreviations, and delete all those rows.